# Can we allocate 10 gb RAM to postgres out of 30gb

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Team, 
Can we allocate 10 gb RAM to postgres out of 30gb on Linux machine. 
If yes can someone share me the steps

Answer (score 0):

Yes one can allocate the Shared Memory with a Kernel Flag this is documented in Postgresql Documentation

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html

Also may want to look into Huge Page same link further down

note this is Shared Memory other settings eat up memory independently,  see the postgres.conf  for more details